# reload map fragment by switching between two tabs

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

I have three Activitys. One who organize the tab switching an two who shows a google map in a map fragment.

If i switch between these two map activities i see both maps. The old one as a picture and the new one as map. for Example: I swicht from Activity A to Activity B, i see in Activity B the map from Activity B and a picture from the map in Activity A.

If i minimize and maximize the application the Activity will be updated and so the picture from Activity A is removed.

![Activity A][1]
![Activity B][2]

How i can fix this problem?

Thanks a lot